# app.UseSerilogRequestLogging() method not working

Tags: logging, middleware, serilog, serilog-sinks-file, serilog-aspnetcore

I am using IApplicationBuilder.UseSerilogRequestLogging() for request logging. I have configured File as sink. But it is not working. I can see every other log events but there is no Event logs that are generated by UseSerilogRequestLogging(). Even if I remove this method from the middleware pipeline, the logs are the same. I have tried to set minimum level of "Microsoft.AspNetCore" to LogEventLevel.Warning but in that case there are no logs.

I have installed Serilog, Serilog.AspNetCore nudget packages.

below is my programe.cs code

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("Logs.txt")
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Host.UseSerilog(logger);

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

and here is my log file

[image: 1]

I am trying for a long time but can't find any solution. Can anyone help?

I have tried to set minimum level of "Microsoft.AspNetCore" to LogEventLevel.Warning but in that case there are no logs.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've faced the same issue in ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET 7.0) project today and it took couple of hours to resolve :-/ Here is the answer for those having the same issue - you should do the following assignment (right after the logger initialization):

```
Log.Logger = logger;
```

Here is more context (Program.cs):

```
// Configuration parameters themselves are not important here, 
// just use the configuration that you need
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Host.UseSerilog(logger);

// Do not forget to assing Log.Logger
Log.Logger = logger;

// ...
    
var app = builder.Build();

// Register Serilog request logging middleware
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
.CreateLogger();

builder.Host.UseSerilog();

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();

"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Please try to include Properties in outputTemplate in SeriLog configuration.

```
"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception} {Properties:j}"
```